# Deserializing complex JSON to C# objects

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize the follow JSON to C# objects. However, I am trying to achieve this without creating classes for the `"1"` objects. This is just a small snippet of the JSON that I will be processing and some of the JSON objects will contain up to 40 child objects, meaning I would have to duplicate a lot of code.

Is there a way to deserialize this style JSON to C# objects without creating classes for 1, 2, etc.?

```
{
"WANConnectionDevice": {
    "1": {
        "WANPPPConnection": {
            "1": {
                "ExternalIPAddress": {
                    "_value": "0.0.0.0",
                    "_timestamp": "2016-08-04T08:51:37.813Z",
                    "_type": "xsd:string",
                    "_writable": false
                    },
                "Password": {
                    "_writable": true,
                    "_timestamp": "2016-08-02T10:40:35.134Z",
                    "_value": "test6",
                    "_type": "xsd:string"
                    },
                "Username": {
                    "_writable": true,
                    "_timestamp": "2016-08-02T10:40:35.134Z",
                    "_value": "test6@test.net",
                    "_type": "xsd:string"
                    },
                "MACAddress": {
                    "_writable": false,
                    "_timestamp": "2016-08-02T16:48:15.188Z",
                    "_value": "",
                    "_type": "xsd:string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "WANIPConnection": {
            "1": {
                "ExternalIPAddress": {
                    "_writable": true,
                    "_timestamp": "2016-08-02T16:48:15.188Z",
                    "_value": "",
                    "_type": "xsd:string"
                    },
                "MACAddress": {
                    "_writable": false,
                    "_timestamp": "2016-08-02T16:48:15.188Z",
                    "_value": "",
                    "_type": "xsd:string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the some of the classes that I can get it to deserialize to which is not practical or good design and what I am hoping to avoid.

```
public class _1
{
    public ExternalIPAddress ExternalIPAddress { get; set; }
    public Password Password { get; set; }
    public Username Username { get; set; }
    public MACAddress MACAddress { get; set; }
}

public class WANPPPConnection
{
    public _1 _1 { get; set; }
}

public class _1
{
    public WANPPPConnection WANPPPConnection { get; set; }
}

public class WANIPConnection
{
    public  _1 { get; set; }
}

public class _2
{
    public WANIPConnection WANIPConnection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does deserialization with classes works? Or do you have problem with it? You can name classes differently (e.g. `Device_1`, `Device_2`, `Connection_1`, etc.) and use [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) to map property to json object `1`, `2`, etc. Why do you think it's *"not practical or good design"*?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert json data to dynamic object.

with **Json.Net**

```
dynamic entity =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
```

then access like this

```
dynamic entity1 = entity.WANConnectionDevice.1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize JSON objects without create a class for each of them, you can use JsonObject class. More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject(v=vs.95).aspx